# How to save the value of the checked checkbox to the database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have here checkboxes that have a different prices and each have a different titles. When the user clicks the checkbox, it will view the price in the total field. When the user now clicks the save button, I want now to save the total to the database and save the titles of the checked checkbox to categories. The titles that will be save to the one row of the database must be separated by comma (,).

This is my HTML codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/master.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="₱20"> Red </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="₱30"> Blue </br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="₱40"> Green </br>
        </br></br>
        Total: <input type="text" name="total" readonly>
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //bind the change event to the checkboxes
        $('input[name="checkbox1"]').change(function(){
            var total = 0;
            //get value from each selected ckeck box
            $('input[name="checkbox1"]:checked').each(function(){
                var tval = $(this).val();
                //remove ₱ sign from value
                //convert it to a flot
                //plus it to the total
                total += parseFloat(tval.replace("₱",""));                
            });
            //finally display the total with a ₱ sign
            $('input[name="total"]').val("₱ " + total);
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't have any idea in how to save the titles of the checkboxes to one row (CATEGORY) of the database. The total price must be save too in the TOTAL field in the database.

Table name: PRODUCTS

Columns: CATEGORY, TOTAL

Example data saved in the database:

CATEGORY:[Red, Blue]

TOTAL: [50]

Comment: You're doing it wrong. First of all - To handle this you need form serialization. Second you don't need to present UK/EUR/US sing in values. Currency sign is not a numerical value

Comment: @bad_boy thank you for your advice but I don't know how to do it. Can I have a sample codes for guides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to colors, you need to get the next sibling from the binded checkbox, then you could create another hidden form for colors since you set the checkbox values as prices. Rough example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="20"> Red </br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="30"> Blue </br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="40"> Green </br>
    </br></br>
    <!-- hidden input colors -->
    <input type="hidden" name="colors" value="" />
    Total: <input type="text" name="total" readonly>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    var colors = [];
    //bind the change event to the checkboxes
    $('input[name="checkbox1"]').change(function(){
        var total = 0;
        //get value from each selected ckeck box
        $('input[name="checkbox1"]:checked').each(function(){
            var tval = $(this).val();
            total += parseFloat(tval);
        });
        //finally display the total with a ₱ sign
        $('input[name="total"]').val("₱ " + total);

        // handle colors
        var color = $.trim($(this)[0].nextSibling.nodeValue); // get the name
        var i = colors.indexOf(color);
        if(i != -1) {
            colors.splice(i, 1); // remove if unchecked
        } else {
            colors.push(color); // push if checked
        }
        var temp = colors.join(', ');
        $('input[name="colors"]').val(temp);

    });

});
</script>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `PRODUCTS` (`CATEGORY`, `TOTAL`) VALUES (?, ?)');

if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $total = (int) str_replace('₱ ', '', $_POST['total']); // remove peso sign
    $colors = $_POST['colors'];
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $colors, $total);
    $stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

Comment: what does VALUES (?, ?) means?

Comment: @Ejardy its a place holder, in this case its called a prepared statments, instead of directly appending your values on your queries which makes it unsafe and SQL injection vulnerable

Comment: @Ejardy here is a good read on that, http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: Is it that the colors will be save in one row with separating with comma like [Red, Blue]?

Comment: @Ejardy yes try my answer, in this logic, i just added `Red, blue, green` inside a hidden input, after submission, just use the simple `$_POST['colors']`, that should be the values

Comment: I'll try your codes, shall I replace your script to mine?

Comment: @Ejardy well yes you can do that, assuming of course the database names, localhosts, usernames, table names, column names, etc. does fit into yours

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally got it! Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

Give them different names

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Red" value="₱20"> Red </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Blue" value="₱30"> Blue </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Green" value="₱40"> Green </br>
```

and change your jquery a little bit:

```
//bind the change event to the checkboxes
$('input[name="checkbox"]').change(function(){..}
```

then access the attribute name:

```
var name = $(this).attr("name");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/usTHG/88/)

---

```
$(function(){
    var total = 0;
    var colors = "";
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(e) {

        var selected_color = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        colors = selected_color.map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("name");
        }).get().join(', ');
        //alert(colors);


         selected_color.each(function(){
           var tval = $(this).val();
           total += parseFloat(tval.replace("₱",""));                
        });
        //alert(total);
    });

    $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "your_script.php",
          data: { category:colors, total: total},
          success:  function(data) {
                  alert('success'); 
          }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
echo $_POST['categor'];
echo $_POST['total'];
```

As for the insert provide this is straight for forward, you did not specify which driver you use, but you can consult @Ghost answer for mysqli

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/usTHG/92/)**

Comment: I'll just add the var tval = $(this).val(); and var name = $(this).attr("name"); to my script. In the php side, how can I call the variable of the checked checkbox for me to save the titles to the one row of the database?

Comment: @Ejardy see my edit if you want to know if the checkboxe is checked, what exactly did you want to insert can you show me an example of the query you need

Comment: I need a codes for saving the total and the titles of the checked checkboxes. That's what I want to do and insert it to CATEGORY. Example when I clicked the two checkbox, it will be save to the one  row of the database like (Red, Blue) and for the total [50].

Comment: Okay I got what you mean. I'll change the name in every checkbox and add var name = $(this).attr("name"); in my script. How can I get the titles of the checked checkbox and insert it to one row?

Comment: I get it now, while I check the checkbox it will display the color(s) that I checked. How can I call it from the form in PHP so that I can save it to database in one row?

Comment: you know how to make ajax request ?

Comment: I don't know (sorry).

Comment: @ meda I got a problem now, the displaying of total price is not displayed in the total textbox.

Comment: The total is already working but the color is not displaying when I calls the variables category and total.

Answer (score 0):

well this seems to be a problem to the super extraordinary label element!!! (i'm so stupid, i can't beat my impetus -.-)

you can put it in a label like this:

Red

so each label identify each checkbox

so you can (if it is PHP):

$labels = $_POST['labels'];

and supposing that you have a normalized DB like this(everything else is only play with strings):

| ID  |  CATEGORY |

for($i=0; $i < count($labels); $i++){
   mysqli_query($con,"Insert into CATEGORY(categoryname) values(' "+$labels[$i]" '); "); 
}

PD: this code wasn't tested.

Answer (score -2):

You need to write some server side code that will take the form data and write it to the database - this would be usually written in PHP or ASP with the bit writeing data to the database in SQL.